# Angular velocity as a function of angle in simple pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Say i've got this simple pendulum with it's corresponding newton equations in polar coordinates.

[image]

equation in $\hat{r}$ axis is actually $mg\cos(\theta)-T = -mL\dot{\theta}$ for clarity, the original equation in the picture doesn't match the directions of the polar basis, even though it doesn't change anything in this problem.

My intention is to derive $\dot{\theta}$ as a function of $\theta$, say $\dot{\theta}(\theta)$.

By this simple variable change, I get:

$\displaystyle \ddot{\theta} = \dfrac{d\dot{\theta}}{dt} = \dfrac{d\dot{\theta}}{d\theta}\dfrac{d\theta}{dt} = \dot{\theta}\dfrac{d\dot{\theta}}{d\theta}$

Replacing this in $\hat{\theta}$ newton's equation, separating variables, and integrating, we get:

$\displaystyle -\frac{g}{L}\int_{0}^{\theta} \sin(\theta) d\theta = \int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}} \dot{\theta} d\dot{\theta}$

Solving both sides and leaving $\dot{\theta}$ alone on one side, we get:

$\dot{\theta}({\theta}) = \displaystyle \sqrt{-2\frac{g}{L}(1-\cos(\theta))}$

Which really bugs me off, since $-1 \leq cos(\theta) \leq 1$, so $1-cos(\theta) \geq 0$ and then $\dot{\theta}(\theta)$ will always be a complex number with imaginary part different than $0$, or $0$.

How is this possible?

Comment: You seem to think that $\dot\theta=0$ when $\theta=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here: $$\displaystyle -\frac{g}{L}\int_{0}^{\theta} \sin(\theta) d\theta = \int_{0}^{\dot{\theta}} \dot{\theta} d\dot{\theta}$$

Notice your lower integral limit is $\theta=0$. If a pendulum is in motion, then for $\theta=0$, you know that $\dot \theta(\theta=0)\neq 0$. Thus, when integrating the LHS, you should really be integrating the following:

$$\int_{\dot \theta_0}^{\dot{\theta}} \dot{\theta} d\dot{\theta}$$

where $\dot\theta_0$ is the angular speed at the bottom.

Therefore, the correct equation should be $$\dot{\theta}({\theta}) = \displaystyle \sqrt{-2\frac{g}{L}(1-\cos\theta)+\dot\theta_0^2}$$